# pdb doesn't respond after pdb.set_trace() call

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I have parent process calling its child. I've put `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` into the child process code.

When I launch the parent with `python -m pdb parent.py` it's getting frozen. The debugger doesn't respond to any command I type. But when I hit `quit` or `continue` it does exits code.

It looks like pdb works, but doesn't produce any output.

```
$ python -m pdb parent.py
n -m pdb parent.py
> d:\scripts\parent.py(53)<module>()
-> '''
(Pdb) c
```

It stops responding now.

According to the trace I get after interruption, it was standing at the line just after the `pdb.set_trace()` call.

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>[2013.06.13-10:02:06] : accessed by child.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "child.py", line 40, in <module>
    sys.stderr = open(Definition_h.ErrLog, 'a', 0, encoding=Definition_h.utf8)
File "d:\scripts\Definition_h.py", line 863, in unicodeOpen
    def unicodeOpen(*args, **kwargs):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 2.5.4\lib\bdb.py", line 50, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_call(frame, arg)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 2.5.4\lib\bdb.py", line 79, in dispatch_call
    self.user_call(frame, arg)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 2.5.4\lib\pdb.py", line 134, in user_call
    self.interaction(frame, None)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 2.5.4\lib\pdb.py", line 187, in interaction
    self.cmdloop()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 2.5.4\lib\cmd.py", line 148, in cmdloop
    import readline
KeyboardInterrupt: !!!<unprintable KeyboardInterrupt object>
Error in sys.excepthook:
```

Comment: Are you actually starting a real `process` to run `child.py` or are you just importing it as a module? Maybe you could post the code that calls `child.py` from your `parent.py` script.

Comment: What happens if you *don't* run it through the debugger? Does that hang as well?

Comment: @Gjallar actually it is called through `os.system("child.py")`

Comment: @doctorlove, No, it doesn't hang up

Comment: @astronaut Ok unfortunately I can only test your szenario on my Linux box, and I can not reproduce the error - maybe you could try to use the more modern `subprocess` module (http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) and see if that works.

Comment: Actually the problem was that my code were redirecting `sys.stdout` to the log file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually the problem was that my code was redirecting `sys.stdout` to the log file

Comment: LOL. Actually upvoting cause that's probably not such a uncommun mistake.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that the script was launched in background mode with the ampersand `&` at the end.

So I got the pdb prompt but no command would execute.